# Need of Forever module for Rest API in Node.js

Tags: node.js, rest, forever

Am planning to develop a Rest Api in Node.js using Express.js Framework and MongoDb as database.

I want to evaluate if Forever module which is used for monitoring a Node.js app is of any use in monitoring a Rest Api.

(PS : Am new to Node.js so kindly be nice to  the question :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not directly. It handles the node process but could be used in any other "normal" node app as well.

BTW: I like the [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) module more than "forever". It is much more powerful - maybe you want to take a look at it.